# Nested resources in Django REST Framework

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, nested-resources

I wish to implement my new API with a nested resource.

```
Example: /api/users/:user_id/posts/
```

Will evaluate to all of the posts for a specific user. I haven't seen an working example for this use case, maybe this isn't the right way for implementing rest API?

Comment: Where are you stuck?  This is fairly straight forward, assuming you already setup OAUTH2.

Comment: How my serlizers will be? which related fields to choose?

Comment: https://github.com/alanjds/drf-nested-routers

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As commented by [Danilo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26458767/django-rest-framework-nested-resources#comment45817506_26461156), the `@link` decorator got removed in favor of `@list_route` and `@detail_route` decorators.

#### Update: `@detail_route` & `@list_route` got deprecated in favor of [`@action`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#extra-link-and-actions).

Here's the alternate solutions:

### Solution 1:

```
@detail_route()
def posts(self, request, pk=None):
    owner = self.get_object()
    posts = Post.objects.filter(owner=owner)

    context = {
        'request': request
    }

    post_serializer = PostSerializer(posts, many=True, context=context)
    return Response(post_serializer.data)
```

### Solution 2:

Try [`drf-nested-routers`](https://github.com/alanjds/drf-nested-routers). Haven't tried this out yet, but looks promising, many are already using it. Looks like an advanced version of what we are already trying to achieve.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @PranjalMittal use **@detail_route(methods=['post'])**. Checkout the doc [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#extra-link-and-actions)

Comment: With action decorator: @action(detail=False, methods=["GET"])

Answer (score 5):

To map `/api/users/:user_id/posts/` you can decorate a `posts` method inside your `ViewSet` with `@link()`

```
from rest_framework.decorators import link
from rest_framework.response import Response


class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    model = User
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    
    # Your regular ModelViewSet things here

    # Add a decorated method like this
    @link()
    def posts(self, request, pk):
        # pk is the user_id in your example
            
        posts = Post.objects.filter(owner=pk)    
        
        # Or, you can also do a related objects query, something like:
        # user = self.get_object(pk)
        # posts = user.post_set.all()

        # Then just serialize and return it!
        serializer = PostSerializer(posts)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: Link decorator got removed in favor of listed_route and detail_rout decorators: https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/commit/f87d32558eb3b36f14a798ec48e4943d25380b92

Answer (score 2):

As [commented by Danilo Cabello](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26458767/django-rest-framework-nested-resources#comment45817506_26461156) earlier you would use `@detail_route` or `@list_route` instead of `@link()`. Please read the documentation for ["Routers", section "Extra link and actions"](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#usage) and ["ViewSets", section "Marking extra actions for routing"](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing) for detailed explanations.